# Do I still need Google Ad Services' script if using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-ads, google-tag-manager, remarketing

I have inherited a site that has both GTM tags (one *Google Ads Remarketing* that fires on every page with a *Conversion ID* but no label, and the *Conversion Linker*), and the standard conversion script as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_conversion_id = 12345;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
```

Do I need to keep the latter? How do I make sure I don't disrupt the stats if making changes?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the standard conversion script and Google conversion tracking from GTM itself. Keeps it clean.

*Note - Google Conversion tracking is different from Google Remarketing tracking*

Steps to setup Google Conversion on Google Tag Manager (Copied from the guideline to avoid link click)- [Link to Google tag manager conversion tracking guide](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6105160?hl=en)

> 1. In Tag Manager, start a new Google Ads tag. From the home screen select New Tag and then Tag Configuration and then Google Ads
>      Conversion Tracking.
> 2. Inside Google Ads (New) In your Google Ads account, click the Tools, Billing, and Settings menu.   Select Measurement: Conversions,
>      which opens to the Conversion Actions table. Select the name of the
>      conversion that you want to use from the Name column. Expand the tab
>      for Tag setup to view the tag details. Select Use Google Tag Manager
>      card. Copy the Conversion ID and Conversion Label.
> 3. In Tag Manager, add the required Conversion ID and Conversion Label values obtained from step 2 to their respective fields. You may
>      optionally add a Conversion Value, Order ID*, and Currency Code. Be
>      sure to use Tag Manager variables for these field values whenever
>      applicable. (For example, most cases will use a variable for Order
>      ID.)
> 4. Choose one or more triggers in the Triggering section to specify when the tag should fire.
> 5. Click Save to complete your tag setup.
> 6. Important: To ensure proper tracking in all browsers, ensure that a Conversion Linker is enabled.
> 7. Preview your changes, and publish when ready.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know how I go. Can't implement yet; live site.

Comment: You can check ot first. Link to official tracking check https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722021?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I will, but can't remove the older script inclusion yet.